# Invalid object name LocalDb Table

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, localdb

I'm trying to run a simple SQL query on a LocalDb database in Visual Studio 2013.

Here's the query in a file `GrabWords.sql`:

```
SELECT * FROM Words
```

where `Words` is a table in the `NextGen.mdf` database.  When I run this, I get the error:

> Invalid object name 'Words'.

For more information, I actually have two databases in the project. In the Solution explorer one is called `NextGen.mdf`, and the other `Cards.mdf`. In server explorer, the first (that I am trying to query) is called `AutoGenEntities` and the other is `CardsDBContext`.

I just want to run this query to test queries and view the database - is there another tool I should be using to do this?

Comment: are you sure you are in the correct DB?  The syntax is correct assuming the existence/access of the table.

Comment: What does this mean and how do I check to see if I am?

Comment: Found it.  Thanks!  There was a dropdown in the toolbar that I completed missed.  Selected the "NextGen" datbase and it started working.

Comment: You could use the query without the dropdown if you used the full object name e.gselect * from [nextgen]. [Dbo]. [Words] for future reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
USE [your Database name]
SELECT * FROM Words
```

This should ensure that you are targeting the correct database.